# Actionscript 3.0 RSS feed

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, rss, cross-domain-policy

This is my first post in here and I wouldn't post a question here without having researched it so if the answer to this is somewhere in here I apologize, but I didn't find it.

So the problem:
I'm reading an RSS feed from Flash CS5 (AS3) and everything works fine and dandy until I upload my .swf to my server. When I test it in Flash everything is great, no compiler errors, nothing from the output, it just reveals the RSS where I tell it to. But when I upload it to the server nothing happens, the RSS simply doesn't load. 
I am using the XML Basics from Flash and no extension or extra scripts, I thought it had something to do with the namespace but whatever I try nothing works.

I know my question is pretty vague and I haven't got the code with me (it's at work) but my hair is turning gray because of this and I have been spending way to much time on something I thought was a simple XML command.

If you need to see some code I will post it first thing tomorrow but the code shouldn't be the problem. It seems like no one on the entire internet has had this problem, I consider myself a pretty capable "googler" but alas.. nothing.

Please help

Thank you

Comment: Could you maybe post the url of the server where your swf is running?

Comment: http://verdandi.is/GAESIN/RSS/RSS_banner.html

Here it is :) the swf file itself is at /RSS_banner.swf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You host the SWF file on the domain `verdandi.is`, but are trying to grab the RSS feed from the domain (or, rather, subdomain) `www.verdandi.is`. The problem is caused since the domain hosting the RSS does not explicitly allow access to its files from SWF files on other domains.

If the SWF is hosted on the same domain, it will work:
http://www.verdandi.is/GAESIN/RSS/RSS_banner.html

This is due to the Flash Player security sandboxing, which you can read more about here:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e08.html

You can allow access from SWF files from other domains by creating a cross-domain policy file as per the link above, or make sure the SWF is accessed from the same domain as the RSS feed.

Comment: Sweet jesus, thank you for you answer! I will try this out first thing tomorrow! I feel like I owe you a beer or any cold alcoholic beverage of your choosing!